# Woocommerce custom shipping charges for (dropdown) selected location?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I need a custom dropdown menu on WooCommerce cart page

here is my requirements.

There should be some custom shipping charges (in dropdown list) for calculating shipping charge,

When someone select the custom location cart should be updated according to that option rate

```
Location-> Option1 -> $150
Location-> Option2 -> $180
Location-> Option3 -> $200
```

Assume product price is $500, so based on the above selection total should be changed automatically

is there any plugin to solve this??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use paid plugin you can use "WooCommerce Advanced Shipping" (http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-advanced-shipping/8634573). This plugin provide you custom location with custom shipping charges. You can check the functionality here (http://www.florienne.co.nz/newsite/shop/).

Thanks.